# Click event triggering after dragging a button

Tags: jquery, onclick, draggable

I have a button with click event and I want to make that button draggable. What I did was,

```
$(function() {
$( "#btn-1834" ).draggable({
        cancel: false
    });
});
```

This is the script for dragging button. But when I drag it will trigger click event.
Is there any solution for that, means I want to drag that button but not trigger click event after dragging and also there must be a click event for that button.

The button Id and modal Id are generated dynamically

Comment: How do you bind your click-function ? According to this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/39u790kv/) the click-event is not triggered while dragging

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this could be setting a flag somewhere, indicating that you're dragging the element, and then clearing the flag after a couple of milliseconds after dragging is done.

Then, in your click handler, check if the flag is set - if it is, don't do anything.

The exact implementation can vary a lot depending on the libraries you're using, so I can't get into anything more specific, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn-1834').draggable({
    cancel: false
}).on('mouseup', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your release code
});
```

Alternatively you can bind your release code to the stop event:

```
$('#btn-1834').draggable({
    cancel: false,
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        // your release code
    })
}) // ..
```

Comment: Would this not cancel out all `mouseup`-related events - including the `click`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use off function like this

```
$(function() {
$( "#btn-1834" ).off('click');
$( "#btn-1834" ).draggable({
        cancel: false
    });
});
```

After the drag function is called you can then use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for click event

Comment: As in the Question: `there must be a click event for that button`. Your answer would be removing this event

Comment: @empiric I didnt read the question fully,my mistake,modified the answer

Answer (score 0):

try the below code.

```
var clickFlag = true;
$('#btn-1834').click(function(){
    if(clickFlag){
        //do the click action
    }
})
$('#btn-1834').draggable({
    cancel: false,
    start:function(e,ui){
        clickFlag = false;
    },
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        clickFlag = true;
    }
});
```

NOTE : I have not tested this yet.

**UPDATE**

NO need of flags or anything.. **just assign the click event AFTER the draggable event and it works fine**

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/8r3n5n1r/)

**UPDATE 2**

Remove the `data-target` attribute and run this code in same order[important]

```
$('#btn-1834').draggable({
    cancel: false
});

$('#btn-1834').click(function(){
    $('#key_edit_modal_1834').modal('show');
})
```

**UPDATE 3**

Change your html to

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default default-key keypress btn_row1 modalbtn" id="btn-<%= key_position.id %>" data-id="<%= key_position.id %>"></button>

<div id="key_edit_modal_<%= key_position.id %>" class="modal fade">
```

and run this after draggable

```
$(document).on('click','.modalbtn',function(){
    $('#key_edit_modal_'+$(this).data('id')).modal('show');
})
```

Comment: sorry Its my mistake, here is one data-target on that button for displaying a modal popup for editing the button text. So what would I do wth that?

Comment: please post those code also. if you are using bootstrap then remove the target and use javascript to trigger the modal

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-default default-key keypress btn_row1" data-target="#key_edit_modal_1834" id="btn-1834"></button>

Comment: But now what the problem is the modal id and button id was generated dynamically. So how can I use the js function with dynamically generated id of button and modal id

Comment: then share some of the dynamically generated html... also please add this in your question

Comment: The button will look like this <button type="button" class="btn btn-default default-key keypress btn_row1" data-target="#key_edit_modal_<%= key_position.id %>" id="btn-<%= key_position.id %>"></button>

Comment: what about the modal?

Comment: <div id="key_edit_modal_<%= key_position.id %>" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Key Edit</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <%= form_for key_position, html: {class: 'key_position_form'}, remote: true do |f| %> <% end %>

       </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

Comment: one more help, how can I trigger draggable with the dynamic id of button? I mean how can I identify which button called for draggable function? Could you please help for this too..

Comment: for initializing draggable you have to run the initializing code when ever a new button is added.

Comment: can you please explain it more... I didn't understand